# How to interpret the zipper of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, type-theory, data-structure

A set with elements of type $a$ typically is represented in type theory by $Set \ a: a \to bool$ or, as an algebraic expression $Set \ a: 2^a$.

The idea is that, for each element of the type $a$, you ask whether it is a member of your set. $2^a$ counts how many distinct subsets there are. For instance, if our set is $\{1,2,3\}$, we get, as possibilities, the empty set $\{\}$, each individual element $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$, any two elements $\{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2\}$, or the full set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. A total of $2^3=8$ subsets.

Now, due to [Conor McBride](http://strictlypositive.org/calculus/) we know that you can get the one-hole context of any type simply by treating it as an algebraic expression and taking its derivative with respect to its type variables. The resulting data structure is called a zipper. In our case:

$$\frac{d}{da} 2^a = 2^a log(2)$$

or expressed as a type:

$$\partial_a \ a \to 2 = \left(a \to 2, log(2)\right)$$

which basically tells us (or at least me) nothing: The logarithm is completely opaque to interpretation.
So this is my question. How to interpret that expression?

I made some progress on my own though, using the following expression:

---

$$b^a = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\binom{a}{n}(b-1)^n}$$

where $\binom{a}{n} = \frac{a!}{n!(a-n)!}$ is the usual binomial coefficient.

In particular, if $b=2$, we get:

$$2^a = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\binom{a}{n}}$$

which simply counts the subsets of size n and then sums them up to find all subsets of arbitrary size. For $n>a$ the expression conveniently vanishes.

Here are the first few terms expressed as polynomials:

$$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & \binom{a}{n} & \text{expanded} \\
\hline
0 & \frac{1}{0!} & 1 \\
1 & \frac{1}{1!}a & a \\
2 & \frac{1}{2!}a(a-1) & \frac{1}{2}\left(-a + a^2\right) \\
3 & \frac{1}{3!}a(a-1)(a-2) & \frac{1}{6}\left(2a - 3a^2 + a^3\right) \\
4 & \frac{11}{4!}a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) & \frac{1}{24}\left(-6a+11a^2-6a^3+a^4\right)
\end{array}$$

While the expanded form is kind of opaque with weird fractions and negative signs, for the column $\binom{a}{n}$ the interpretation is pretty clear:

- There is only one way to take no elements from $a$ to generate a set. You'll get the empty set.
- There is one way for each $x : a$ to generate a set. You'll get the set $\left\{x\right\}$ for what ever choice $x$ you make.
- There are $a \left(a-1 \right)$ ways to generate a set of two elements $\left\{x, y\right\}$ from $a$: You pick your first element, and then, because sets have no duplicates, you pick your second element from a type $a-1$ which no longer includes your first pick. However, because in sets order doesn't matter, there are always $2!=2$ choices that lead to the same outcome. - You can pick $x$ first and $y$ second,  or $y$ first and $x$ second. So then, that choice is ignored by dividing by $2!$.
- etc.

As expected, this also works for when your source type $a$ is smaller than your target set. For instance, attempting to take two elements from the unit type $1$ results in $\frac{1}{2!}1(1-1) = 0$ - there are $0$ ways to do that.

Ok, so with all that out of the way, lets differentiate term-wise by $a$:

$$\frac{d}{da}\binom{a}{n} = \binom{a}{n} \left(H(a) - H(a-n)\right)$$

where $H(j)$ is the $j^\text{th}$ Harmonic number.

Or, simply by applying the product rule to the above table:

$$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & \frac{d}{da}\binom{a}{n} & \text{expanded} \\
\hline
0 & \frac{0}{0!} & 0 \\
1 & \frac{1}{1!} & 1 \\
2 & \frac{1}{2!} \left((a-1) + a \right) & \frac{1}{2}\left(-1 + 2a\right) \\
3 & \frac{1}{3!}\left((a-1)(a-2) + a(a-2) +a(a-1) \right) & \frac{1}{6}\left(2 - 6a + 3a^2\right) \\
4 & \frac{11}{4!}(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) + a(a-2)(a-3) + a(a-1)(a-3) + a(a-1)(a-2) & \frac{1}{24}\left(-6+22a-18a^2+4a^3\right)
\end{array}$$

That looks fine and dandy, right? Well, there is a problem now. I'm pretty sure these polynomials never ever become integer-valued for any integer. Nor do their summed-up forms. And they even give multiple ways to pick an empty set with no hole.

For instance, take $n=2$ elements from a type $a \cong 3$, leaving one of them a hole:

$$\frac{1}{2!}\left((3-1) + 3 \right) = \frac{5}{2}$$

In principle I read this as:
You can either take the hole first and then any of the three values, or you can first take one of the three values, and then a hole with the two possible remaining values, and the order doesn't matter, so divide by 2.

But I *think* there should still be an integer number of ways to do this, right? Is there any way to make sense of that fraction? Or did I do something wrong here?

If I'm not mistaken, given my type used at the beginning $a = \{1, 2, 3\}$, a 2-element subset with one hole would look something like this:

$$\left\{\_, 1\right\} | \left\{\_, 2\right\} | \left\{\_, 3\right\} | \\ \left\{1, \_ \right\} | \left\{2, \_ \right\} | \left\{3, \_\right\}$$

where the first three expressions have holes of type $a \cong 3$, the last three of type $a-1 \cong 2$ (after removing the appropriate element), but they are also paired up, each of the top line with the one below it.

The closest to interpreting $\frac{5}{2}$ I got is that, ignoring the no order constraint, we're dealing with something of type $3 + 2$ - that is $3 \ or\  2$ - for the hole and, perhaps, the constraint can only be fulfilled once the hole is filled back in? But that doesn't yet resolve how there apparently can be several ways - even "negative" ways - to get a hole from an empty set or similar such problems.

Comment: In the papers you link to, derivation seems to only be defined for [positive types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/positive+type) but $A\to B$ is a [negative type](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/negative+type). Do you know a specific paper defining the derivative on function types?

I'd expect things to still kind of work for coinductive types but it looks really weird for function types. The zipper uses the tree-like structure of the term and a function has no such structure.

Comment: Ah, interesting, good catch. I do not. That might well be where these problems stem from, then. Though to a good extent it does still seem to work out. I feel like I'm at least *close* with my interpretation at the end there.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see a good way of interpreting minus. For division, in the presentation of bags at the end of [this paper](http://strictlypositive.org/derivcont.pdf), they quotient by automorphisms instead of dividing by the factorial. You could also try to use the series expansion of the logarithm. But really, if you want to extend the zipper to functions, you probably should just set $\partial_A B^A\cong B^A$ because the whole point of the zipper is to move around to edit the structure in a functional way, and this can be done directly for functions.

Comment: It does kind of make sense to have $\partial_B B^A=B \times B^{A-1}$: you represent $f:A\to B$ as $(f(x),f_{|A\setminus\{x\}})$ for some $x\in A$. So maybe it's more that you can't differentiate with respect to types that are in a contravariant position.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure that this is relevant but [this paper](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/papers/rational.pdf) offers an interpretation of negative types under certain conditions. Under that interpretation, the negatives are a form of backtracking to ensure, in the case of $2^a$, that no value is used more than once.

Comment: Perhaps what you say is more practical (I'm not sure I follow though, what do you mean by $\partial_A B^A \cong B^A$, Can you elaborate, please?), though I'd still like to know whether and how this can be interpreted in a sound, rigorous way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64427/discussion-between-xavierm02-and-kram1032).

Comment: As xavierm02 stated, the "differentiation of types" papers do not define differentiation for arbitrary types. You can look at the theory of (virtual) species. [Brent Yorgey's Pearl](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~yorgey/pub/species-pearl.pdf) is a good place to start given a programming background. See his [thesis](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~yorgey/pub/thesis.pdf) for more details. If you find the previous interesting, I highly recommend [Combinatorial Species and Tree-like Structures](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Combinatorial+species+and+tree-like+structures) if you can get your hands on it.